# \0 doesn't print the number next to it

Tags: c, escaping, c-strings

I found this trick/problem on the web and would like to understand what's happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char s[] = "S\0C5AB";
    printf("%s", s);
    printf("%d", sizeof(s)); // 7
    printf("  -- %d", strlen(s)); // 1
}
```

Everything worked as expected.

But when put a number after `\0` `sizeof` and `strlen` both ignore `\0` and the number next to it.

```
int main(){
    char s[] = "S\065AB";
    printf("%s   ", s); // S5AB
    printf("--- %d", sizeof(s)); // 5
    printf("  -- %d", strlen(s)); // 4
}
```

Link to the above code: https://godbolt.org/z/7qfYq51E4

What's happening here?

Comment: `'\0'` terminates the string. That is how functions like `strlen` know where the end is. For the second example read this: [Octal representation inside a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815076/octal-representation-inside-a-string-in-c)

Comment: [Not ignoring it. You specified a different escape sequence.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: Read the chapter about "octal escape sequences within C strings"... Your '\065' is a legal ASCII value that represents the character '5'... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's just a trick question I saw on a website.

Comment: Also be aware that `strlen` and  `sizeof` are very different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Octal representation inside a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815076/octal-representation-inside-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C provides for 1, 2 or 3 [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) digits to be specified within a string.

In the first string `char s[] = "S\0C5AB";` the single digit after the backslash is compiled to the value 0.

This definition is equivalent to:

```
char s[] = { 'S', 0, 'C', '5', 'A', 'B', '\0' }; // 0 == '\0'. They are the same
```

The second example posted contains 3 octal digits in sequence, and 065 == ASCII '5'

This means the 2nd example (`char s[] = "S\065AB";`) is an array like this:

```
char s[] = { 'S', '5', 'A', 'B', '\0' }; // \065 ==> '5'
```